# How to work with login_hints using Azure custom policy for B2C and B2B combined users

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

I need to redirect to the Azure login page based on the user directory i.e either B2C or B2B directory. I had created the custom policy based on the Azure starter pack. When I execute the custom policy URL with the query parameter login_hint in B2C it does not populate in the username textbox. For B2C Login I had customized the login screen.

Now when I redirect to the B2B login screen and add the same parameter then the username is populated in the sign in screen.

Now the questions is 
1. B2C not populating the username textbox. Is it due to custom login UI?
2. How to pass the login_hint from B2C to B2B login URL. I am using domain_hint to redirect the user directly to the B2B login screen. But it does not pass the login_hint to the B2B login screen. Do I need to add or do changes in the custom policy files?

Comment: As per the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811325/how-do-i-include-email-in-the-redirect-to-azure-ad-b2c default value is loading in B2C login screen after adding `DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}"` in  `<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName> 
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />` in TrustFrameworkBase.xml file

Comment: But the above didn't load login hint in b2b sign in page.