# How to pass B2C login hint to B2B sign in page when using Azure custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

As the link [pass login_hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728015/how-to-work-with-login-hints-using-azure-custom-policy-for-b2c-and-b2b-combined) I am able to pre-populate the username in the B2C login screen. But When I click on the B2B login button from B2C or when I redirect to the B2B sign in url the login_hint is not passed as a parameter. If I manually add the login_hint in the b2b url then it loads the username.