# Set Default Value for DisplayName attribute for local Account in Azure AD B2C SignUp Policy

Tags: xml, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

On the local Account Sign Up form, `displayName` attribute is not a required field and we don't want to make it a required field.

But when a user does not provide any value for that, it is storing `unknown` value as it set to that in the policy.

```
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
```

I want to set the `givenName` attribute value as default when it is saving the profile instead of `unknown`.

I have tried like as below, but not helping

```
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="{givenName}" />

<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" 
    PartnerClaimType="givenName" DefaultValue="unknown"  />
```

Comment: This is because AAD considers `displayName` a required field. So even if your policy doesn't enforce it, AAD still needs _something_ there. Is there a reason why you're not requiring `displayName` but _are_ requiring `givenName`?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, We have few other IDP's like facebook, linkedIn etc are incorporated into the policy which populates the displayName by default, we just want to maintain the same experience not making it a mandatory field across the platform. I am looking if that can be achieved without forcing the user, if not I have to make it mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but I believe this is where we can use [ClaimsTransformations](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%201.md#claims-transformation).  It's not really documented so I can't point you in the direction of good howto's .

Borrowing from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46424607/185123), I believe you can do this:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateDisplayNameFromGivenName" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="givenName" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

---

Then you need to call your ClaimsTransformation in your TechnicalProfile.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccount-Registration-GivenName">
  <DisplayName>Hello World Account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.registration</Item>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromGivenName" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    ...
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    ...
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AzureActiveDirectoryStore-WriteUserByEmail-ThrowIfExists" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SSOSession-AzureActiveDirectory" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score -2):

check link below it may help you sir.its to late im sorry 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile

Comment: Hey Adnan - this question is about Azure AD B2C not SQL