# Pre populate email on Azure Active directory sign up policy(B2C)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to pass the email from client application to Microsoft Azure Active directory and use it to pre populate the email(username) field sign up page.
We can use `login_hint` on sign in policy, but it is not working on sign up policy. Is there any similar field we can use in sign up policy ?

Comment: you can write you custom code to automatically add user (register )in azure add https://github.com/rahulshukla422/azure-ad-register-user/blob/master/ConsoleApp3/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [***Rahul Shukla***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7160482/rahul-shukla) for your suggestion Posting this an answer so it could help other users as well.

you need to write the [***custome code***](https://github.com/rahulshukla422/azure-ad-register-user/blob/master/ConsoleApp3/Program.cs) For Prepopulating the email(username) field on sign up page.

You can refer this [**StackPost**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380468/azure-ad-b2c-pre-populate-a-custom-attribute-in-the-signup-policy) same kind of requirement has disscused here as well!

Currently all B2C Custom Policy Samples that are supported by Microsoft can be found here : ***https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack***